# Photos framework: Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, photosframework

I am getting this error when I am trying to play multiple videos using this swift library (https://github.com/piemonte/player). Not sure if it's related to that player, or to the Photos framework or what though.

What happens is, I have a view that will display either a photo or a video. Everything works fine a few times until a few videos have played and then this message will pop up, followed by all the videos not being able to play and in their place you just see a black screen, and then I get a memory usage error.

I am using a library called SwipeView and here is some relevant code which may be helpful.

```
func swipeView(swipeView: SwipeView!, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView! {
    let asset: PHAsset = self.photosAsset[index] as PHAsset

    // Create options for retrieving image (Degrades quality if using .Fast)
    //        let imageOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    //        imageOptions.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Fast
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    let screenSize: CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let targetSize = CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height)

    var options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Exact
    options.synchronous = true

    if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.Image) {
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: {(result, info) in
            if (result.size.width > 200) {
                imageView = UIImageView(image: result)
            }
        })

        return imageView
    } else if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.Video) {
        self.currentlyPlaying = Player()


        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {result, audio, info in
            self.currentlyPlaying.delegate = self
            self.currentlyPlaying.playbackLoops = true
            self.addChildViewController(self.currentlyPlaying)
            self.currentlyPlaying.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

            var t = result as AVURLAsset
            var url = t.valueForKey("URL") as NSURL
            var urlString = url.absoluteString

            self.currentlyPlaying.path = urlString
        })

        return self.currentlyPlaying.view
    }
    return UIView()
}


    func swipeViewItemSize(swipeView: SwipeView!) -> CGSize {
    return self.swipeView.bounds.size;
}

func swipeView(swipeView: SwipeView!, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) {
    self.currentlyPlaying.playFromBeginning()
}

func swipeViewCurrentItemIndexDidChange(swipeView: SwipeView!) {
    self.currentlyPlaying.stop()
}
```

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: It looks like every time a video is played, you create a new `Player()` and add it as a child view controller. Do you ever remove it when its done? That could cause memory issues.

Comment: @JackWu. Oh, that is probably it. I'll take a look at that later, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I had this same "**Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died**" error.

Usually followed by a **memory warning**. 
I tried to find retain cycles, but it wasn't it.

The problem for me had to do with the known fact that the *resultHandler* block of any *PHImageManager* `request...()` is **not** called on the main queue.

So we cannot run *UIView* code directly within those blocks without asking for trouble later on in the app life.

To fix this we may for instance run all *UIView* code that would be executed within the scope of the *resultHandler* block inside a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)`

I was having this problem because I did not realize that one of the functions that I was calling within one of the *resultHandler*.s of my app did eventually call some *UIView* code down the line. 
And so I was not forwarding that call to the main thread.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is occurring because of the TargetSize only. The PHImageManagerMaximumSize option is the culprit. Set the CGSIZE as you want for the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you create a new Player-object everytime you start playing a video:

```
 self.currentlyPlaying = Player()
```

I would recommend you to either remove it after the file has finished playing or to create one player which you will reuse. Otherwise it will stay in the memory.v