# UIImagePickerController crashes "Connection to assets was interrupted or assets died"

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I've been wrestling with this issue ad nauseam but still cant figure out what is causing the crash. I instantiate the camera from a button, thereafter when the user chooses the photo i add the photo to my images array and reload the collectionView. After approximately 20 times i get the output in the console "Connection to assets was interrupted or assets died" subsequently followed by a crash. When i remove the collectionView?.reloadData() method from within the delegate method "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo" it doesnt crash. This has left me extremely obfuscated. See code below:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: Dictionary) {
if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {

images.append(image)

// when i remove this method the app doesnt crash! 
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView?layoutIfneeded()

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is the solution, note the compression size is hardcoded, you may want to adapt the code to your needs or refactor and improve the method.

```
func imageCompression(_ imageDict: [String : UIImage]) -> [String : Data] {
    var compressedImages = [String : Data]()

    for (key, value) in imageDict {
        var resizeAttempts = 5
        var compressionRatio: CGFloat = 1
        var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value, compressionRatio)

        if imageData?.count <= 90000 {
            compressedImages[key] = imageData
        } else {

            while imageData?.count > 90000 && resizeAttempts > 0 {
                resizeAttempts -= 1
                compressionRatio = compressionRatio * 0.5
                imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value, compressionRatio)
                compressedImages[key] = imageData
                print("image size now is \(imageData?.count)")

            }
        }
    }
    return compressedImages
}
```

Comment: A quick search around suggests `reloadData()` is a memory-intensive method, which I guess would go some ways to explaining the crash. For it to crash after a number of times suggests to me that resources or handles aren't being released - could this be the case?

Comment: @EdKing probably . This answer seems to be related too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914846/photos-framework-connection-to-assetsd-was-interrupted-or-assetsd-died

Comment: @EdKing it is nothing to do with reloadData() being memory-intensive because I have put reloadData() into another button and inserted an image from my bundle and reloaded it over 100 times and there was no problem, it only happens when i call it inside the delegate method of UIImagePickerController, Warren Burton, I have read that post but its not relative, I process my images as suggested in the answer of that thread. This problem is truly baffling.

Comment: Sounds like you need to dispatch the update to the main thread? That's suggested in the question linked to by @WarrenBurton

Comment: @EdKing I have tried all of that, no luck. Create a skeleton project and try for yourself.

Comment: Solved it finally, I scaled the image received from the delegate method to a smaller size using CoreGraphics then reloaded it and voila! Happy days.

Comment: @silly_cone Can you please post the code in answer to solve such scenario? I am facing similar issue, where I am clicking photo, and showing it to collectionview (using NSArray) and while doing the same process multiple times, it crashes.

Comment: @Mrunal The problem was that the camera was taking images at a high resolution and each image was taking up huge amounts of memory, so after a number of images being added the threshold for iOS RAM allocation is reached which is currently set at 500mb, when the threshold is breached iOS kills your app. The solution is to reduce the size of your images to something smaller, let me know if you want the code that reduces image size, of course reducing image size outputs lower quality images.

Comment: On re-reading your comment, here is the code.